# Unexpected Package View in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I'm trying to create a subpackage. Currently my package hierarchy looks like this:

```
com.mycompany.a.b.c
```

I created this:

```
com.mycompany.a.b.c.d
```

When I view the new package in Eclipse Project Explorer I see the package in **two** places:

(1) subordinate to com.mycompany.a.b.c, like so:

```
com.mycompany.a.b.c
   com.mycompany.a.b.c.d
```

(2) **also** at the same level as com.mycompany.a.b.c like so:

```
com.mycompany.a.b.c
com.mycompany.a.b.c.d
```

In windows explorer view there is only one com.mycompany.a.b.c.d package -- the one that is subordinate to com.mycompany.a.b.c

Although I really don't care where the new package gets displayed. I was expecting to see it as in example (2) above. It's really disconcerting to see it in two places.

In Eclipse when I try deleting one package, the other gets deleted too.

There's something fundamental I'm not understanding.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried creating a class or file in the c level package and deleting one folder at the d level? It may cause one of the folders to stay.

Comment: The c level package had a class when I added the d level package.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of both of packages you see in Eclipse?

Comment: Good news. I exited Eclipse and started it again. The d level package appears at the save level as the c level. (They are peers.)

Comment: Sounds like an Eclipse bug. Thanks, Jason for your help.

Comment: You're very welcome, glad it reduced to a simple solution.